# jQuery scroll with animate does not scroll to the correct location

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, behavior

My goal is to have my page scroll to a specific div if a user has visited the page before. I am using the following code:

```
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $("#userResults").offset().top - 72
  }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo"
);
```

#userResults is the appropriate target div. The problem is, when the page loads, it scrolls to roughly the middle of the page. I've tried rearranging the divs out of the fear that one div that contained canvas elements was throwing things off, but that didn't work. I tried hardcoding a scroll value; I tried retrieving the page height and div heights to force a scroll position, but none of that worked. Further, when I test against different screen sizes, the scroll goes to different points around the middle of the page.

What is the most frustrating is that when I click on links on the loaded page that target divs, they go to the exact location. Those use the following code:

```
$('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
    if (target.length) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 72)
      }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

That last block of code comes from the template that I'm building from, which comes from: https://startbootstrap.com/themes/creative

Here's a codepen of the relevant code: [codepen](https://codepen.io/jeffbartelli/pen/ExyKzyN) The specific code block can be found around line 99 of the javascript. Also, the codepen doesn't demonstrate the problem behavior, probably because it doesn't allow me to create variables in local storage.

I've been coding for about a year, so I'm no expert and may need a little handholding. How do I get this thing to scroll to the right position on load?

Comment: That's a lot of code to comb through, but I noticed the element has an inline style of `display: none` but not _how_ it's removed, if at all. Are you absolutely sure that's not the place you are meant to scroll to?

Comment: @msg I'm sure it's not right. I reference the correct div and the scroll goes to somewhere in the middle of the div that precedes it.